# Can I send data to a server without using it's IP adress?

Tags: networking

Example situation:

data = "hello, we need to meet!"

say I wanna send the data above on a server, but I don't want to use the servers real IP address (so that it wouldn't be logged on a "network activity log" both the OS and the router) Is it possible?

or maybe some alternatives? All I want is: I wanna send a data on a server but I don't want the server's IP address to be logged on anywhere.

Comment: You cannot send data over TCP without a destination address.

Comment: You can send to the broadcast address and all machines on the same network will see it - if you’re on the same network as the server. But the same logging mechanisms will apply. Why do you think bypassing logging mechanisms would be possible? That kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

By using desktop applications like Socket you can send data over the internet.

Socket is capable enough to send data over the network especially if no firewalls or proxies are involved in between.

But, my suggestion  is better go through proper channel otherwise If the setup changes, you may land  into trouble.

**If you mean to say "how can I send SMS (small messages)?", as you have shown in the question.**

Short messagess (SMS) are basically based on SMPP protocol it can't send directly.

If you use the SMS gateway or an existing Api where you can make a http request from php, there are lot of SMS service providers like VAS, and free open source SMS geteway like KANNEL which can be used to send & receive SMS.